# How to print all distinct permutations with duplicate values

Tags: java, duplicates, permutation

I originally had a method to create every permutation of a list of Integer. I added some code to not repeat the same permutation (in case of duplicate items in the list). However, some repetition is still present. I am not sure how to fix this. This is the code i have:

```
static void permute(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
    for (int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (i < arr.size() - 1) {
                while (arr.get(i) == arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    if (i < arr.size() - 2) {
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
        permute(arr, k + 1);
        Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
    }

    if (k == arr.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the list is previously put in numerical order.

My code works by setting the first number in the list to something stationary, then moving up a position all the way down to the last item in the list. Then working backwards it swaps  and progressively moving backwards through the recursion to swap elements. The while statement should skip duplicates by skipping past identical values that would otherwise be swapped.

A sample input would be permute([11, 11, 43, 61], 0) and it at the moment results in the output:

```
[11, 11, 43, 61]
[11, 11, 61, 43]
[11, 43, 11, 61]
[11, 43, 61, 11]
[11, 61, 43, 11]
[11, 61, 11, 43]
[43, 11, 11, 61]
[43, 11, 61, 11]
[43, 61, 11, 11]
[61, 11, 43, 11]
[61, 11, 11, 43]
[61, 43, 11, 11]
[61, 11, 43, 11]
[61, 11, 11, 43]
```

Where [61, 11, 11, 43] and [61, 11, 43, 11] are duplicates that should not be present.

Comment: Can you please give an example input, the current and the desired output? Also, explain your code, how does it work?

Comment: Note that by using `Set`s you could easily eliminate duplicates. However, that would not prevent them from being created, only from being added to the final solution.

Comment: Also note that `Collections.swap` on a `List<Integer>` can be extremely slow if the method is not fed with an `ArrayList` (a `LinkedList` for example). The name `arr` therefore is not well chosen as it is not an **array** but an arbitrary list.

Comment: I don't want them to be created in order to reduce the runtime, sometimes my lists can have up to 15 elements and I don't have days to let it run. The variable arr is residual from when I used to have it as an array, but later decided that a list better bit code that comes in later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
//swap integer in array.
public static void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}

// This function finds the index of the smallest character
// which is greater than 'first' and is present in str[l..h]
public static int findCeil(int str[], int first, int l, int h) {
    // initialize index of ceiling element
    int ceilIndex = l;

    // Now iterate through rest of the elements and find
    // the smallest character greater than 'first'
    for (int i = l + 1; i <= h; i++)
        if (str[i] > first && str[i] < str[ceilIndex])
            ceilIndex = i;

    return ceilIndex;
}

// Print all permutations of str in sorted order
public static void permutations(int arr[]) {

    // Get size of string
    int size = arr.length;


    // Sort the string in increasing order
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    // Print permutations one by one
    boolean isFinished = false;

    while (!isFinished) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        // Find the rightmost character which is smaller than its next
        // character. Let us call it 'first char'
        int i;
        for (i = size - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
                break;

        // If there is no such chracter, all are sorted in decreasing order,
        // means we just printed the last permutation and we are done.
        if (i == -1)
            isFinished = true;
        else {
            // Find the ceil of 'first char' in right of first character.
            // Ceil of a character is the smallest character greater than it
            int ceilIndex = findCeil(arr, arr[i], i + 1, size - 1);

            // Swap first and second characters
            swap(arr, i, ceilIndex);

            // Sort the string on right of 'first char'
            Arrays.sort(arr, i + 1, size);

        }
    }
}
```